# How to do an instanceof check with Scala(Test)

Tags: java, scala, junit, scalatest

I'm trying to incorporate ScalaTest into my Java project; replacing all JUnit tests with ScalaTests. At one point, I want to check if Guice's Injector injects the correct type. In Java, I have a test like this:

```
public class InjectorBehaviour {
    @Test
    public void shouldInjectCorrectTypes() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ModuleImpl());
        House house = injector.getInstance(House.class);

        assertTrue(house.door() instanceof WoodenDoor);
        assertTrue(house.window() instanceof BambooWindow);
        assertTrue(house.roof() instanceof SlateRoof);
    }
}
```

But I have a problem doing the same with ScalaTest:

```
class InjectorSpec extends Spec {
    describe("An injector") {
        it("should inject the correct types") {
            val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ModuleImpl)
            val house = injector.getInstance(classOf[House])

            assert(house.door instanceof WoodenDoor)
            assert(house.window instanceof BambooWindow)
            assert(house.roof instanceof SlateRoof)
        }
    }
}
```

It complains that the value `instanceof` is not a member of `Door`/`Window`/`Roof`. Can't I use `instanceof` that way in Scala?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

With Scalatest 2.2.x (maybe even earlier) you can use:

```
anInstance mustBe a[SomeClass]
```

Comment: This is the recommended approach on recent versions of ScalaTests

Comment: also available `a[Type]` so you can be grammatically correct ;)

Comment: I was looking for that! :)

Comment: `tiger shouldBe a [Tiger]` is the current syntax http://www.scalatest.org/at_a_glance/FlatSpec

Comment: @jhegedus `mustBe` is also correct, if you use http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.MustMatchers which you want for FreeSpec.

Answer (score 124):

Scala is not Java. Scala just does not have the operator `instanceof` instead it has a parametric method called `isInstanceOf[Type]`.

You might also enjoy watching a [ScalaTest Crash Course](https://youtu.be/-0PsDZZUi5c).

Comment: well, that doesn't really answer the question. ScalaTest has built-in support for type check. See the answer from @martin-g

Comment: How to do it if "Type" it's a trait?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but it should be the same: `isInstanceOf[TraitName]`.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to be less JUnit-esque and if you want to use ScalaTest's matchers, you can write your own property matcher that matches for type (bar type erasure).

I found this thread to be quite useful: http://groups.google.com/group/scalatest-users/browse_thread/thread/52b75133a5c70786/1440504527566dea?#1440504527566dea

You can then write assertions like:

```
house.door should be (anInstanceOf[WoodenDoor])
```

instead of

```
assert(house.door instanceof WoodenDoor)
```

Comment: +1 That looks very nice, and even understandable for non-programming people (assuming they know what an instance is :-)).

Comment: If syntax sugar is what you are after, with some refactoring you might be able to write house.door should be (madeOf[Wood]) or house.door should be (madeOf[Bamboo]).

Comment: Also see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scalatest-users/HeOKgs5PC2o/discussion

Answer (score 18):

The current answers about isInstanceOf[Type] and junit advice are good but I want to add one thing (for people who got to this page in a non-junit-related capacity).  In many cases scala pattern matching will suit your needs.  I would recommend it in those cases because it gives you the typecasting for free and leaves less room for error.

Example:

```
OuterType foo = blah
foo match {
  case subFoo : SubType => {
    subFoo.thingSubTypeDoes // no need to cast, use match variable
  }
  case subFoo => {
    // fallthrough code
  }
}
```

Comment: The recommended way to test a pattern match in ScalaTest is to use `inside(foo)` instead of `foo match). See http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#matchingAPattern

Answer (score 3):

Consolidating Guillaume's ScalaTest discussion reference (and another discussion linked to by James Moore) into two methods, updated for ScalaTest 2.x and Scala 2.10 (to use ClassTag rather than manifest):

```
import org.scalatest.matchers._
import scala.reflect._

def ofType[T:ClassTag] = BeMatcher { obj: Any =>
  val cls = classTag[T].runtimeClass
  MatchResult(
    obj.getClass == cls,
    obj.toString + " was not an instance of " + cls.toString,
    obj.toString + " was an instance of " + cls.toString
  )
}

def anInstanceOf[T:ClassTag] = BeMatcher { obj: Any =>
  val cls = classTag[T].runtimeClass
  MatchResult(
    cls.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass),
    obj.getClass.toString + " was not assignable from " + cls.toString,
    obj.getClass.toString + " was assignable from " + cls.toString
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use 2.11.8 to do the assertion with collections. The newer syntax is as follows:

```
val scores: Map[String, Int] = Map("Alice" -> 10, "Bob" -> 3, "Cindy" -> 8)
scores shouldBe a[Map[_, _]]
```

Comment: Due to erasure you cannot check the `Map`'s type parameters. What you wrote is the same as writing `scores shouldBe a[Map[_, _]]`. This is mentioned here: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingAnObjectsClass