# Or operator with scalaTest matcher

Tags: scala, scalatest

Using scalatest idiomatic matcher how can I check if a class is instance of A or B?

I try with or but it does not work

```
e shouldBe a [ChannelWriteException] || e shouldBe a [ConnectException]
```

Here [How to do an instanceof check with Scala(Test)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561898/how-to-do-an-instanceof-check-with-scalatest) explain how to use isInstanceOf, but not how to make an or
Regards.

Comment: I base my question in that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561898/how-to-do-an-instanceof-check-with-scalatest but there they dont specify how to make an "or" which is what my question it´s about

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do an instanceof check with Scala(Test)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561898/how-to-do-an-instanceof-check-with-scalatest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `Matcher#should(Matcher[T])` with `Matcher#or[U <: T](Matcher[U])`

example,

```
  it("test instanceOf A or B") {
    val actual = new Thread()
    actual should (be (a [RuntimeException]) or be (a [Thread]))
  }
```

if actual does not match the expected, it errors out with proper messaging,

```
  it("test instanceOf A or B") {
    val actual = new String()
    actual should (be (a [RuntimeException]) or be (a [Thread]))
  }
```

error

```
"" was not an instance of java.lang.RuntimeException, but an instance of java.lang.String, and 
"" was not an instance of java.lang.Thread, but an instance of java.lang.String
```

The conventional way, (*I'm still in 2000s*)

```
val actual = new Thread()
assert(actual.isInstanceOf[RuntimeException] || actual.isInstanceOf[Thread])
```

### Reference

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#logicalExpressions

[Is there anyway we can give two conditions in Scalatest using ShouldMatchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965148/432903)

Comment: I find I need some extra brackets. But basically the same `actual should (be(a[RuntimeException])).or(be(a[Thread]))`